# Abrir imagen cargada desde picturebox en visor de imagenes de windows

Tags: c#, picturebox

Tengo mi formulario en el cual hago uso de un picturebox que me muestra la imagen que previamente he cargado desde mi base de datos a través de un boton como se ve en la imagen, ahora la pregunta reside en como podría ver esa imagen que cargue previamente en el picturebox a traves de la accion de mi boton, hacer que se visualice en el visor de imágenes de windows dando doble click en el evento del picturebox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago uso de la siguiente linea de código con la que trato de ver la imagen en el visor pero me arroja una excepción que detallo a continuación.

```
Process.Start(pboxIma.Name);
```

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' en System.dll
>
> El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: que tiene pboxIma.Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **PictureBox** no da una forma obvia de obtener la ruta en donde está la imagen que el carga, para ello se recomienda usar la **propiedad** **Tag** del propio **PictureBox**, la cual es una propiedad digamos "genérica" y cuando se carga la imagen en el **PictureBox** se le da a la **propiedad** **Tag** el valor de donde se seleccionó la imagen. Por ejemplo si obtienes la imagen de un **OpenFileDialog** sería:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{                
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    pictureBox1.Tag = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

Como ves aquí cuando guardamos la imagen en el **PictureBox**, ponemos en la propiedad **Tag** la ruta de dicha imagen, y entonces para hacer lo que pides sería:

```
Process.Start(pictureBox1.Tag);
```

En caso de que la imagen venga de una base de datos, pues tendrás que guardarla físicamente en tu computadora además de mostrarla en tu **PictureBox**.

Para ello después de que tu imagen se carga en tu **PictureBox** pondrías:

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(ruta);
Process.Start(ruta);
```

Bien podrías crear una carpeta llamada temporal donde guardes todas tus imágenes y después las borres.

Comment: El problema es que yo no cargo mi imagen en el picture box desde un open file dialog sino desde una columna de mi base de datos con lo cual no seria valido el obtener mediante tag, modifique la pregunta para que se entendiera mejor

Comment: @Carrobe90, revisa lo nuevo que puse

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto la solución a este problema que se me presentaba, gracias a la colaboración de @japv.

En el método del picturebox click, añadí el siguiente código en base a la respuesta, mas el que previamente tenia, el cual como resultado final me permite hacer la visualización de la imagen tan solo con dar doble click.

```
private void pboxIma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dao.Class_Backup daoBack = new dao.Class_Backup();
        pboxIma.Tag = @"\TEMP_IMAGE.JPEG";
        string ruta = daoBack.Crear_Carpeta_Visor() + "" + pboxIma.Tag.ToString();
        pboxIma.Image.Save(ruta, format: ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Process.Start(ruta);
    }
```

El método Crear_Carpeta_Visor realiza la función de la creación de la carpeta.

```
 public String Crear_Carpeta_Visor()
    {
        string ruta = @"D:\TEMP";
        if (!Directory.Exists(ruta))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creando el directorio: {0}", ruta);
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
        }
        return ruta;
    }
```

Y por ultimo un método que esta implementado en el closing del formulario principal para eliminar la carpeta y archivos que usen temporalmente.

```
  public void Eliminar_Carpeta_Visor()
    {
        String ruta = @"D:\TEMP";
        if (Directory.Exists(ruta))
        {
            Directory.Delete(ruta, recursive: true);
        }            
    }
```